# No instance of Constructor matches the argument list but argument list matches documentation and template code

Tags: c++, constructor, sdk, visual-studio-2019, 3dsmax

To start off, I am working with 3ds Max SDK. I don't expect many people to have used this SDK but the issue itself is not SDK specific from what I can tell.  I suspect this is a Visual Studio issue but I'm not sure how to fix.

Here is a section the code that is currently showing the error.

```
#include <actiontable.h>

namespace {
    const ActionTableId creatorToolActionTableId = 0x52510afc;  //1381042940
    const ActionContextId creatorToolActionContextId = 0x59b927b6;
}

// Setting up the Creator Tool ActionTable
class CreatorToolActionTable : public ActionTable {
public:
    CreatorToolActionTable()
        : ActionTable(creatorToolActionTableId, creatorToolActionContextId, TSTR(GetString(IDS_CT_CATEGORY)))
    {
        static ActionDescription ctActions[] = {
            //Creator Tool          1
            {
            ID_CREATOR_TOOL,
            IDS_CREATOR_TOOL_DESC,
            IDS_CREATOR_TOOL,
            IDS_CT_CATEGORY,
            },

            //Creator Tool Help     2
            {
            ID_CREATOR_TOOL_HELP,
            IDS_CREATOR_TOOL_HELP_DESC,
            IDS_CREATOR_TOOL_HELP,
            IDS_CT_CATEGORY
            }
        };
        BuildActionTable(nullptr, sizeof(ctActions) / sizeof(ctActions[0]), ctActions, hInstance);
    };
    ~CreatorToolActionTable() {};
    BOOL IsEnabled(int) override { return TRUE; };
    BOOL IsChecked(int) override { return FALSE; };
};
```

The error is showing at `ActionTable(creatorToolActionTableId, creatorToolActionContextId, TSTR(GetString(IDS_CT_CATEGORY)))`.
The error is the same as the title that there is not a constructor for `ActionTable::ActionTable matching the arguments (const ActionTableId, const ActionContextId, WStr)`.

When referring to the SDK documents and examples of code, there is maxMenuDemo which is my main reference for this.  The section of code in maxMenuDemo.cpp is:

```
#include <actiontable.h>

namespace {
const ActionTableId kMenuDemoActionTableId = 0x44370c39;
const ActionContextId kMenuDemoActionContextId = 0x44370c3A;
}

class MenuDemoActionTable : public ActionTable
{
public:
    MenuDemoActionTable()
            : ActionTable(kMenuDemoActionTableId, kMenuDemoActionContextId, TSTR(GetString(IDS_AT_CATEGORY)))
    {
        // You can comment this out, if you want to load files from disk.
        RegisterDynamicResources(GetColorManager()->GetAppFrameColorTheme());

        // This packages up our actions into an ActionDescription for our ActionTable
        static ActionDescription spActions[] = { 
            ID_ACTION1, // ID
            IDS_ACTION1_DESC, // menu1
            IDS_ACTION1, 
            IDS_AT_CATEGORY,

            ID_ACTION2, 
            IDS_ACTION2_DESC, 
            IDS_ACTION2, 
            IDS_AT_CATEGORY };

        BuildActionTable(nullptr, sizeof(spActions) / sizeof(spActions[0]), spActions, hInstance);
    };

    ~MenuDemoActionTable()
    {
        UnregisterDynamicResources();
    };

    MaxIcon* GetIcon(int cmdId) override;
    BOOL IsChecked(int /*cmdId*/) override { return FALSE; };
    BOOL IsEnabled(int /*cmdId*/) override { return TRUE; };

    // Qt support for loading icon resources
    using Theme = IColorManager::AppFrameColorTheme;
    void RegisterDynamicResources(const Theme& theme = Theme::kDarkTheme);
    void UnregisterDynamicResources();

private:
    std::unique_ptr<MaxIcon> m_MaxIcons[2];
    // The registered path for the compiled icon bundles - see the maxMenuDemo.qrc 
    // files,  and the custom build tool on the file on how these .rcc files
    // are being generated.
    QString m_registeredRCCPath;
};
```

To me, the code is the exact same in terms of what is being input for `CreatorToolActionTable : Actiontable(creatorToolActionTableId, creatorToolActionContextId, TSTR(GetString(IDS_CT_CATERGORY)))` and for `MenuDemoActionTable(): ActionTable(kMenuDemoActionTableId, kMenuDemoActionContextId, TSTR(GetString(IDS_AT_CATEGORY)))`.  Therefore, I would assume it would work for my code and I should not have the error since the template code also does not have the error.

The only real differences between my code and the template is I have removed references to Qt and icons as I am not using them.

There are two constructors for ActionTable:
`CoreExport ActionTable(ActionTableId id, ActionContextId contextId, MSTR& name)` and
`CoreExport ActionTable(ACtionTableId id, ActionContextId contextId, MSTR& name, HACCEL hDefaults, int numids, ActionDescription* pOps, HINSTANCE hInst)`

I have tried using the second constructor as well on its own and received the same errors when the parameters matched the documentation.
Here is the link to the SDK documentation (specifically for ActionTable class): [3ds Max 2021 SDK](https://help.autodesk.com/view/MAXDEV/2021/ENU/?guid=__cpp_ref_class_action_table_html)

I am running this on VS2019 targeted for VS2015.

Is the issue with VS2019 or am I completely missing something?

Comment: What is `TSTR(GetString(IDS_AT_CATEGORY))`? It looks like a temporary, and according to your snippets 3rd argument should be a non-const l-value reference (which cannot be bound to a temporary).

Comment: I can't help but think that your [mcve] isn't minimal enough, as it's hard to tell *what* "constructor" you have problem with in th shown code.

Comment: Also please [edit] your question to include a *full* and *complete* copy-paste of the build output. When you get errors like this you typically also get some informational notes that often helps in understanding the problem (for example by seeing what the actual arguments are, which can then be compared to the expected arguments).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen TSTR(GetString(IDS_AT_CATEGORY)) will return the 'Caption' from the string table.  In this instance, GetString(IDS_AT_CATEGORY) will return "MenuDemo_ActionTable".  This is just used in 3ds Max for the category that the actions will be in when searching for macros.

Comment: I never heard of this library, so it doesn't tell me anything. But knowing C++ I can tell that 3rd argument of this constructor requires an existing object, which lives somewhere, you can take address of it etc. If `TSTR` does not return a reference, it most likely returns a temporary and cannot be used here.

Comment: Are you able to compile the sample/template?

Make sure you are using the right requirements for the version of the sdk you are trying to use. The 2020 and 2021 SDK use VS 2017, more information can be found in the documentation here:

https://help.autodesk.com/view/MAXDEV/2021/ENU/?guid=__developer_about_the_3ds_max_sdk_sdk_requirements_html

Comment: Hi everyone, I wanted to say that the issue was with VS. Not sure why it gave me the error overall.  The code complied perfectly fine with no errors and that when adding the plugin to 3ds Max, everything registered in the program properly. My guess is VS not reading argument types correctly in that MSTR would work with TSTR.

Comment: It's likely that your `_UNICODE` setting for the project was incorrect.  3ds Max uses unicode strings, and in `strclass.h` you can see the definition of `TSTR` will resolve to either `WStr` or `CStr` depending on this.  Likewise `MSTR` is defined with a different test for `MCHAR_IS_WCHAR`.  This stuff is legacy and pretty much defunct.  If 3ds Max ever changes the SDK in such a way that both these macros do not evaluate to UTF-16, I promise all hell will break loose.